# KineticJS hide anchors until mouseover

Tags: kineticjs

I have used the demo code to resize images using anchors. I want to hide the anchors until mouseover and found some demo code. But only the bottomRight anchor works properly. Can someone tell me what is wrong?

```
<div id="container"></div>
<script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.0.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function update(activeAnchor) {
    var group = activeAnchor.getParent();

    var topLeft = group.find('.topLeft')[0];
    var topRight = group.find('.topRight')[0];
    var bottomRight = group.find('.bottomRight')[0];
    var bottomLeft = group.find('.bottomLeft')[0];
    var image = group.find('.image')[0];

    var anchorX = activeAnchor.x();
    var anchorY = activeAnchor.y();

    // update anchor positions
    switch (activeAnchor.name()) {
      case 'topLeft':
        topRight.y(anchorY);
        bottomLeft.x(anchorX);
        break;
      case 'topRight':
        topLeft.y(anchorY);
        bottomRight.x(anchorX);
        break;
      case 'bottomRight':
        bottomLeft.y(anchorY);
        topRight.x(anchorX); 
        break;
      case 'bottomLeft':
        bottomRight.y(anchorY);
        topLeft.x(anchorX); 
        break;
    }

    image.setPosition(topLeft.getPosition());

    var width = topRight.x() - topLeft.x();
    var height = bottomLeft.y() - topLeft.y();
    if(width && height) {
      image.setSize({width:width, height: height});
    }
  }
  function addAnchor(group, x, y, name) {
    var stage = group.getStage();
    var layer = group.getLayer();

    var anchor = new Kinetic.Circle({
      x: x,
      y: y,
      stroke: '#666',
      fill: '#ddd',
      strokeWidth: 2,
      radius: 8,
      name: name,
      draggable: true,
      dragOnTop: false
    });

    anchor.on('dragmove', function() {
      update(this);
      layer.draw();
    });
    anchor.on('mousedown touchstart', function() {
      group.setDraggable(false);
      this.moveToTop();
    });
    anchor.on('dragend', function() {
      group.setDraggable(true);
      layer.draw();
    });
    // add hover styling
    anchor.on('mouseover', function() {
      var layer = this.getLayer();
      document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
      this.setStrokeWidth(4);
      layer.draw();
    });
    anchor.on('mouseout', function() {
      var layer = this.getLayer();
      document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
      this.strokeWidth(2);
      layer.draw();
    });

    group.add(anchor);
  }
  function loadImages(sources, callback) {
    var images = {};
    var loadedImages = 0;
    var numImages = 0;
    for(var src in sources) {
      numImages++;
    }
    for(var src in sources) {
      images[src] = new Image();
      images[src].onload = function() {
        if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
          callback(images);
        }
      };
      images[src].src = sources[src];
    }
  }
  function initStage(images) {
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
      container: 'container',
      width: 578,
      height: 400
    });
    var darthVaderGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
      x: 270,
      y: 100,
      draggable: true
    });
    var yodaGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
      x: 100,
      y: 110,
      draggable: true
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

    /*
     * go ahead and add the groups
     * to the layer and the layer to the
     * stage so that the groups have knowledge
     * of its layer and stage
     */
    layer.add(darthVaderGroup);
    layer.add(yodaGroup);
    stage.add(layer);

    // darth vader
    var darthVaderImg = new Kinetic.Image({
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      image: images.darthVader,
      width: 200,
      height: 138,
      name: 'image'
    });

    darthVaderGroup.add(darthVaderImg);

    addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, darthVaderImg.getX(), darthVaderImg.getY(), 'topLeft');
     addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, darthVaderImg.getX()+darthVaderImg.getWidth(), darthVaderImg.getY(), 'topRight');
     addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, darthVaderImg.getX()+darthVaderImg.getWidth(), darthVaderImg.getY()+darthVaderImg.getHeight(), 'bottomRight');
     addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, darthVaderImg.getX(), darthVaderImg.getY()+darthVaderImg.getHeight(), 'bottomLeft');

    darthVaderGroup.on('dragstart', function() {
      this.moveToTop();
    });
    // yoda
    var yodaImg = new Kinetic.Image({
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      image: images.yoda,
      width: 93,
      height: 104,
      name: 'image'
    });

    yodaGroup.add(yodaImg);

    yodaGroup.on('mouseover', function(){
     addAnchor(yodaGroup, yodaImg.getX(), yodaImg.getY(), 'topLeft');
     addAnchor(yodaGroup, yodaImg.getX()+yodaImg.getWidth(), yodaImg.getY(), 'topRight');
     addAnchor(yodaGroup, yodaImg.getX()+yodaImg.getWidth(), yodaImg.getY()+yodaImg.getHeight(), 'bottomRight');
     addAnchor(yodaGroup, yodaImg.getX(), yodaImg.getY()+yodaImg.getHeight(), 'bottomLeft');
     layer.draw();
    });

    yodaGroup.on('mouseout', function(){
    var yodaKids = yodaGroup.getChildren();
    for(var i=1; i<yodaKids.length; i++)
          yodaKids[i].hide(); // .remove() would also work, or .destroy()
    layer.draw();
    });

    yodaGroup.on('dragstart', function() {
      this.moveToTop();
    });

    stage.draw();
  }

  var sources = {
    darthVader: 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg',
    yoda: 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/yoda.jpg'
  };
  loadImages(sources, initStage);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use opacity--even at near invisible opacity the anchors will still respond to mouse events**

This code will cause the circle to appear when hovered:

```
function addAnchor(x,y){
    var anchor = new Kinetic.Circle({
        x:x,
        y:y,
        radius: 20,
        fill: 'red',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4,
        draggable: true,
        opacity:.01
    });
    anchor.on("mouseout",function(){this.opacity(.01);layer.draw()});
    anchor.on("mouseenter",function(){this.opacity(1.00);layer.draw()});
    layer.add(anchor);
}
```

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/4V9vs/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I still cannot get all the anchors to work on each image

Comment: I added a demo showing how to hide Kinetic objects until mouseover.  Good luck with your project!